# Mdi Child window frame color

Tags: windows, winapi, dll

I'm developing an MDI application. I need to know whether I can change the window frame color of the child or not.

If yes, how do I do it using the Windows API?  I tried using `SetSysColor()` but was unsuccessful.

Comment: "*I'm developing an MDI application*" - why?  MDI has been deprecated for over a decade. Microsoft hasn't maintained the API, it has fallen into disarray, and doesn't produce good results in modern Windows systems. Why can't you use a different UI model?

Answer (score 0):

You have to trap the `WM_NCPAINT` message and paint the entire frame 
yourself.

The color of the caption bar is controlled by the system 
color and there is no way to change the color of one caption bar with 
system calls without affecting all other windows in the system.

A simple basic sample can be found [here](https://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-d/dislog/titlebar/article.php/c1987/Draw-on-Title-Bar.htm).